# Could we define the MACRO name as specific string?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Could we implement a MACRO to register the name for prints ? like below:

**1.C**

```
O_PRINT_NAME_REGISTER(NET_TRACE)
O_PRINT_NAME_REGISTER(MAIN_TRACE)

void example(void)
{
     NET_TRACE(" net log");  // LINE 20
     MAIN_TRACE(" main log"); // LINE 21
}
```

**Expected Output**

> example - 20: net log
>  example - 21: main log

How to define `O_PRINT_NAME_REGISTER()`?

Comment: NET_TRACE/MAIN_TRACE are expected to be a MACRO NAME.

Comment: I don't think you can do this.  In order to know the line number NET_TRACE must be a macro, but a macro can't create a macro.

Comment: Your requirement seems confusing to me. Do you want a macro which could print trace and line number ??

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to define a macro from another macro. From C99 6.10.3.4/3 "Rescanning and further replacement":

> The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence
>   is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles
>   one,

It is possible to prepare a function using macro, but then you would **not** get the line number and function name information.

For example:

```
#define O_PRINT_NAME_REGISTER(FN_NAME) static void FN_NAME(char *arg) {  \
                                          printf("%s\n", arg);           \
                                       }
```

[ideone link](http://ideone.com/vrEuje)

---

You can instead define a macro that takes macro like `NET_TRACE` as argument and passes function name and line number information to the appropriate function or pass an appropriate logging function pointer to a generic function which can process function name and line number information.

Comment: I think this would be a perfect opportunity to use function pointers.

Comment: @ RastaJedi, how ? Could you help providing the details ?